# Small loss magnitude

Tags: neural-networks, optimization

I'm training a model that has "a priori" very small magnitudes of the loss function (MSE for regression purposes). The model fails to learn which I suppose is due to the fact that the loss is very small and hence the gradients will also be terrible small which can be considered a vanishing gradient problem even though I'm using a fully connected neural network with just 2 hidden layers and 40 neurons each. How would you solve this problem? Is there any loss function other than MSE that somehow scales the loss to proper values in order to avoid terrible small magnitudes or even scaling the gradients by multiplying them with a proper constant?

Comment: What is the machine learning problem that you are trying solve? I belive that in most cases you are able to scale up your output values in data, and thanks to that have bigger loss values.

Comment: Multiply all of your output values by $1000000$ so you're working in millimeters instead of kilometers. Then know that your predicted output is in kilometers, and report it in your desired units after doing an appropriate conversion. (Or whatever units make sense to your particular problem)

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot do that because I'm using physical biases and scaling the outputs would violate those physical constraints. I'm using a neural network to learn a scalar that is then manipulated according to the physical constraints to give the desired cost function. The problem is that the cost function itself needs to be always near zero, the closer from zero the best and it appears that the model stops learning when the loss function gets closer to zero which makes sense but in turn yields poor results.

Comment: The cost function is a physical equation itself that needs to be zero for the given dataset itself. So, the goal is to minimize that equation with respect to the inputs. There are no targets in this case or the target should be always zero which is the result of that equation.

Comment: @SaulSantos I do not follow why changing the units from kilometers to millimeters (for instance) would be any kind of violation.

Comment: Ok, let's suppose we want to learn an implicit equation $f$ where $g$ is represented by a neural network: $f(x,y)=0 = \frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial y} +  \frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial x} + b $, where $b$ is a constant that is different for each input pair. So, I want to learn $g$ in such a way that it respects this equation that itself is the cost function. The problem here is that the gradients get too small (around $10^{-8}$ for each weight for a model with just 2 hidden layers with 40 neurons) because $b$ is always a very small variable and scaling it would violate the equation $f$.

Comment: I see, but I've never heard of physical biases. Why you ever want to use such technique? `b` definitely seems to be a good candidate for network input.

Comment: Hi. Theoretically, if you want to learn a function via a neural network you are using a black-box approach that has no idea about the laws of physics that in some cases cannot be violated depending on the application. By using physical biases you can restrict the neural network in such a way that it respects those laws. Also, by doing so there's evidence of better generalization capabilities.